# Android Studio automatically undoes class rename

Tags: android-studio, ide

I have an odd issue with Android Studio. Occasionally I will try to rename something (right now it's a class), it will go through the process, rename it, and immediately undo the rename with no information or warning. This extremely frustrating and super odd. Does anyone know why this happens or what to do about it?

I've tried `git clean -fdx` and invalidate caches and restart multiple times, renaming the file then the class, and renaming to a random name to make sure it's not the name itself, but it won't go away.

Comment: Did you try the latest version of Android Studio? Anyway, please specify the Android Studio and OS version.

Comment: I would suggest to try reproducing with another project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just broke down and manually created a file with the new name, pasted the old code in, changed the old name to the new name, deleted the old file, and when through and manually fixed all the ensuing build errors. Still not sure what the problem was in the first place, but this did the trick.